# Getting the TMSI from the SIM card

Tags: android, sim-card

Is it possible, in Android or any other mobile OS, to access the encrypted information passed from the SIM card to the cellular network? I mean the mobile signature, or the TMSI number. I need this data after it is encripted by the sim. I mean the IMSI after it is encrypted by the SIM to be sent to the network.
Thanks :)

Comment: Did you finished this project successfully?

Answer (score 2):

**Impossible. Android so far does not provide any direct API's and/or other interfaces to SIM card,**  except for some basic information like country code, operator name, etc, which is kindly provided by `TelephonyManager`.

Additionally, SIM interface normally is connected to modem CPU, not application one, thus eliminating any possible hacks/workarounds.

Comment: Oh really? I'm not sure if we both mean the same thing but with the [`TelephonyManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html) you can query a couple of SIM things like SIM country ISO code, SIM operator code, SIM operator name, SIM serialnumber and SIM state.

Comment: Correct, but seems like topic owner wants initiate APDU communication with the SIM card.

Comment: True. I was just trying to tell you that the statement should be a bit specified.

Comment: Doesn't answer need an update? I hear something about `SIM Toolkit`. Is it an android tool / API  to send APDU to SIM?

Comment: No, my answer is still valid. Google will never provide such public API for security purposes. Operators does not want that. The only way to communicate to the SIM card from Android application is to use rooted device that has patched Android framework with Seek For Android project patches. You either patch this by your own if you have Nexus device, or use one of the devices from this list: https://code.google.com/p/seek-for-android/wiki/Devices

Comment: And what is _SIM Application Tool Kit_? I saw it in some new smart phones installed by default. I hear that we can send proactive commands to SIM using it.

Comment: I think that's the tool that helps interfacing with applications that reside on the SIM card. It does not mean it is capable of transferring raw data APDU's between SIM and host.

Answer (score 0):

As I know SIM doesn't encrypt the IMSI information,that's the one reason to use TMSI.

Comment: thanks for you answer. I want to make an application that will do something like rSAP (remote SIM access profile) on Android. for that, I need to read from the SIM whatever it is that is needed for making a phone call. Can you please tell me what those things are? Does the SIM API on Android give me access to that information, so I could use the phone as a "SIM card reader"?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Exactly, SIM doesn't do that. Its all done using Hardware of phone. And TMSI don't have anything to do with phone. It is used in radio interfaces just to secure user information and confidentiality. Phone will be always identified by IMSI not TMSI. 
Basically they uses some key values. And those keys do the twist. Algorithm A5 and A8 are used for key purpose.

Pankaj Singh